# My Visual Studio Code terminal won't reset to cd anymore

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

[this is my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZHdn.png). Every time I run python manage.py runserver this happens. How can I make to where I don't have to reset my VSC every time I want access to the terminal again?

I did try to control break but my laptop keyboard doesn't include the break button. I tried FN+CTRL+B, CTRL+B, and FN+CTRL+F11. None worked.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 0):

From toolbar you can click `Terminal > New Terminal` - then you can switch between your sessions

Answer (score 0):

To access the `BREAK` key, you can use the on screen keyboard (search for osk).

Also, you should be able to use `ctrl`+`c` to stop Django (will interrupt a running program in the terminal for most programs). You can test this by pressing `ctrl`+`c` at the terminal and check if `^C` shows up or is the text copied.

Answer (score 0):

The terminal in vscode can be created multiply.

Click as the following picture so that you can operate in another cmd.

[image]

And generally we just use `Ctrl+C` for killing command line statements nowadays.